# MySql queries are stuck which Stored procedures are executed

Tags: mysql

> Below are my MySql configurations. The average connections are 190.
>   The connection limit is set to 300. Not sure which config is causing
>   the issue. The queries include creating the index and creating temp
>   tables that are triggered by stored procedures.

**There are 50 to 60 threads created on average.**
The total system ram is 100GB and has better system configurations. Please suggest what are all the changes required in MySql

```
'innodb_adaptive_flushing', 'ON'
'innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm', '10'
'innodb_adaptive_hash_index', 'ON'
'innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts', '8'
'innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay', '150000'
'innodb_api_bk_commit_interval', '5'
'innodb_api_disable_rowlock', 'OFF'
'innodb_api_enable_binlog', 'OFF'
'innodb_api_enable_mdl', 'OFF'
'innodb_api_trx_level', '0'
'innodb_autoextend_increment', '64'
'innodb_autoinc_lock_mode', '1'
'innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size', '134217728'
'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown', 'ON'
'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct', '25'
'innodb_buffer_pool_filename', 'ib_buffer_pool'
'innodb_buffer_pool_instances', '8'
'innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup', 'ON'
'innodb_buffer_pool_load_now', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_size', '21474836480'
'innodb_change_buffer_max_size', '25'
'innodb_change_buffering', 'all'
'innodb_checksum_algorithm', 'crc32'
'innodb_checksums', 'ON'
'innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled', 'OFF'
'innodb_commit_concurrency', '0'
'innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct', '5'
'innodb_compression_level', '6'
'innodb_compression_pad_pct_max', '50'
'innodb_concurrency_tickets', '5000'
'innodb_data_file_path', 'ibdata1:12M:autoextend'
'innodb_data_home_dir', ''
'innodb_deadlock_detect', 'ON'
'innodb_default_row_format', 'dynamic'
'innodb_disable_sort_file_cache', 'OFF'
'innodb_doublewrite', 'ON'
'innodb_fast_shutdown', '1'
'innodb_file_format', 'Barracuda'
'innodb_file_format_check', 'ON'
'innodb_file_format_max', 'Barracuda'
'innodb_file_per_table', 'ON'
'innodb_fill_factor', '100'
'innodb_flush_log_at_timeout', '1'
'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit', '1'
'innodb_flush_method', ''
'innodb_flush_neighbors', '1'
'innodb_flush_sync', 'ON'
'innodb_flushing_avg_loops', '30'
'innodb_force_load_corrupted', 'OFF'
'innodb_force_recovery', '0'
'innodb_ft_aux_table', ''
'innodb_ft_cache_size', '8000000'
'innodb_ft_enable_diag_print', 'OFF'
'innodb_ft_enable_stopword', 'ON'
'innodb_ft_max_token_size', '84'
'innodb_ft_min_token_size', '3'
'innodb_ft_num_word_optimize', '2000'
'innodb_ft_result_cache_limit', '2000000000'
'innodb_ft_server_stopword_table', ''
'innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree', '2'
'innodb_ft_total_cache_size', '640000000'
'innodb_ft_user_stopword_table', ''
'innodb_io_capacity', '300'
'innodb_io_capacity_max', '2000'
'innodb_large_prefix', 'ON'
'innodb_lock_wait_timeout', '300'
'innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog', 'OFF'
'innodb_log_buffer_size', '41943040'
'innodb_log_checksums', 'ON'
'innodb_log_compressed_pages', 'ON'
'innodb_log_file_size', '50331648'
'innodb_log_files_in_group', '2'
'innodb_log_group_home_dir', '.\\'
'innodb_log_write_ahead_size', '8192'
'innodb_lru_scan_depth', '1024'
'innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct', '75.000000'
'innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm', '0.000000'
'innodb_max_purge_lag', '0'
'innodb_max_purge_lag_delay', '0'
'innodb_max_undo_log_size', '1073741824'
'innodb_monitor_disable', ''
'innodb_monitor_enable', ''
'innodb_monitor_reset', ''
'innodb_monitor_reset_all', ''
'innodb_old_blocks_pct', '37'
'innodb_old_blocks_time', '1000'
'innodb_online_alter_log_max_size', '134217728'
'innodb_open_files', '300'
'innodb_optimize_fulltext_only', 'OFF'
'innodb_page_cleaners', '4'
'innodb_page_size', '16384'
'innodb_print_all_deadlocks', 'OFF'
'innodb_purge_batch_size', '300'
'innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency', '128'
'innodb_purge_threads', '4'
'innodb_random_read_ahead', 'OFF'
'innodb_read_ahead_threshold', '56'
'innodb_read_io_threads', '4'
'innodb_read_only', 'OFF'
'innodb_replication_delay', '0'
'innodb_rollback_on_timeout', 'OFF'
'innodb_rollback_segments', '128'
'innodb_sort_buffer_size', '1048576'
'innodb_spin_wait_delay', '6'
'innodb_stats_auto_recalc', 'ON'
'innodb_stats_include_delete_marked', 'OFF'
'innodb_stats_method', 'nulls_equal'
'innodb_stats_on_metadata', 'OFF'
'innodb_stats_persistent', 'ON'
'innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages', '20'
'innodb_stats_sample_pages', '8'
'innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages', '8'
'innodb_status_output', 'OFF'
'innodb_status_output_locks', 'OFF'
'innodb_strict_mode', 'ON'
'innodb_support_xa', 'ON'
'innodb_sync_array_size', '1'
'innodb_sync_spin_loops', '30'
'innodb_table_locks', 'ON'
'innodb_temp_data_file_path', 'ibtmp1:12M:autoextend'
'innodb_thread_concurrency', '9'
'innodb_thread_sleep_delay', '0'
'innodb_tmpdir', ''
'innodb_undo_directory', '.\\'
'innodb_undo_log_truncate', 'OFF'
'innodb_undo_logs', '128'
'innodb_undo_tablespaces', '0'
'innodb_use_native_aio', 'ON'
'innodb_version', '5.7.21'
'innodb_write_io_threads', '4'
'internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine', 'InnoDB'
'join_buffer_size', '524288'
'lock_wait_timeout', '31536000'
'log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes', '0'
'master_info_repository', 'FILE'
'master_verify_checksum', 'OFF'
'max_allowed_packet', '524288000'
'max_connect_errors', '100'
'max_connections', '300'
'max_delayed_threads', '20'
'max_digest_length', '1024'
'max_error_count', '64'
'max_execution_time', '0'
'max_heap_table_size', '16777216'
'max_insert_delayed_threads', '20'
'max_join_size', '18446744073709551615'
'max_length_for_sort_data', '1024'
'named_pipe', 'OFF'
'net_buffer_length', '16384'
'net_read_timeout', '30'
'net_retry_count', '10'
'net_write_timeout', '60'
'pseudo_thread_id', '162'
'query_alloc_block_size', '8192'
'query_cache_limit', '1048576'
'query_cache_min_res_unit', '4096'
'query_cache_size', '1048576'
'query_cache_type', 'OFF'
'wait_timeout', '28800'
```